# Parsing XML Response in R

Tags: xml, r, xml-parsing

I currently have an XML Response from a SOAP API call which I have parsed into an `XMLInternalDocument` fine. I am having trouble extracting specific nodes from the parsed response.

Below is the approach I have taken to try to get the elements out of the XML response.

```
library(XML)

responseparsed <- XML::xmlParse("response2.xml")
getNodeSet(responseparsed, "//Category")
```

The response I get is an empty list (i.e. no content to my understanding)

```
# list()
# attr(,"class")
# [1] "XMLNodeSet"
```

I am ultimately wanting to get my XML response into a data.frame if possible, so would really appreciate some pointers because I also couldn't get `xmlToList` to work either because of the `<header>` and <`body>` both being in the XML packet.

If you take the below excerpt and create an XML file called `response2.xml` then you should be able to reproduce my problem.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
  <soap:Header>
    <wsa:Action>RetrieveResponse</wsa:Action>
    <wsa:MessageID>urn:uuid:mymessageid</wsa:MessageID>
    <wsa:RelatesTo>urn:uuid:relatestoid</wsa:RelatesTo>
    <wsa:To>http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing/role/anonymous</wsa:To>
    <wsse:Security><wsu:Timestamp wsu:Id="Timestamp-c74b9126-8c79-4624-abd1-de4021ce1096">
      <wsu:Created>2015-08-13T12:38:54Z</wsu:Created>
      <wsu:Expires>2015-08-13T12:43:54Z</wsu:Expires>
    </wsu:Timestamp></wsse:Security>
  </soap:Header>
  <soap:Body>
    <RetrieveResponseMsg xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
      <OverallStatus>OK</OverallStatus>
      <RequestID>myanonrequestid</RequestID>
      <Results xsi:type="List">
        <Client>
          <ID>6212693</ID>
        </Client>
        <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true" />
        <ID>537</ID>
        <ObjectID xsi:nil="true" />
        <ListName>All Subscribers</ListName>
        <Category>2151</Category>
        <Type>Private</Type>
      </Results>
      <Results xsi:type="List">
        <Client>
          <ID>6212693</ID>
        </Client>
        <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true" />
        <ID>1217</ID>
        <ObjectID xsi:nil="true" />
        <ListName>list A</ListName>
        <Category>3038</Category>
        <Type>Private</Type>
      </Results>
      <Results xsi:type="List">
        <Client>
          <ID>6212693</ID>
        </Client><PartnerKey xsi:nil="true" />
        <ID>1434</ID><ObjectID xsi:nil="true" />
        <ListName>List B</ListName>
        <Category>6362</Category>
        <Type>Private</Type>
      </Results>
      <Results xsi:type="List">
        <Client>
          <ID>6212693</ID>
        </Client>
        <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true" />
        <ID>1435</ID>
        <ObjectID xsi:nil="true" />
        <ListName> List C</ListName>
        <Category>6362</Category>
        <Type>Private</Type>
      </Results>
    </RetrieveResponseMsg>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Category` inherits default namespace from `RetrieveResponseMsg` ancestor element. To reference element in namespace using XPath, you need to map a prefix to point to the namespace uri, and use that prefix in your XPath. I'm not very familiar with `r`, but I think it will be something like :

```
getNodeSet(responseparsed, "//d:Category", c(d="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI"))
```